# local dae models three.js on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, three.js

I'm trying to make a rails application which uses three.js but I'm having some trouble with loading the .dae files.

In the line to load the 3d model:

```
loader.load( 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/392/iphone6.dae', loadCollada);
```

using this .dae file [from another tutorial][1] it works, but when I try using local files or other files uploaded on other online storage (tried only dropbox for now) I get a CSFR.

Initially, for development purposes, I'd like to use this website with local files. In a second moment I would like to use an amazon bucket to store the models.

What can I do to make sure my files work on the rails application?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I believe the fact that the s3 file works is because the bucket might have [cors enabled](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html). I still would liketo know if there is a way to use local files.

Comment: This has little to nothing to do with three?

Comment: @pailhead the loader.load line is used to load the 3d model to use in three

Comment: I was trying to improve the question but had a hard time coming up with a suggestion. I know nothing about ruby on rails, but i know that the only language that runs in the browser is javascript. Three should know first and foremost how to parse a 3d mesh given a format, but it also knows how to initiate xhr requests. With this in mind, perhaps you should try editing your question to be more general - about javascript working with ruby, or loading files with ruby.